# Assign columns names to a csv dataset

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm currently working on a dataset that consists of the following data:

```
paper_id, word_attributes, class_label
```

Now there are a total of 3700 word_attributes columns representing a binary value. Is there a method in python using which I could assign the column headers? Thanks.

Comment: How are the column headers stored?

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps read the csv file using:

```
a = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
```

it will create a `numpy.recarray` where each column can be called by a key, like `a['paper_id']`. When `dtype=None`, "the dtypes will be determined by the contents of each
column, individually".

---

EDIT: as suggested by @askewchan, you have to pass `names=True` to keep the original names for the csv columns.

Comment: You may also need `names=True` to keep the column names as field names.