# Assign column names to a csv dataset

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm currently working on a dataset that consists of the following data:

paper_id, word_attributes, class_label

Now there are a total of 3700 word_attributes columns representing a binary value. The problem is that the column headers have not been assigned to the dataset. So how do I go about assigning 3700+ column names in the .csv file? Any suggestons?

Thanks.

Edit:
The .csv file is as follows;

```
100157,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.....,Agents
100598,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.....,IR
..............................
..............................
```

Comment: Can you explain your data structure further? Maybe paste here a portion of it.

Comment: Can't you just title the headers `paper_id,attr1,attr2,...attr3700,class_label`?

Comment: Well manually doing so would take a lot of time. I thought there maybe a way to assign headers programatically.

Comment: Do the columns have descriptive names or is it just "attr1", "attr2"? Because if it's the latter, you can do something like `','.join(['attr%d'%i for i in range(3700)])` to generate the bulk of it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign columns names to a csv dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302042/assign-columns-names-to-a-csv-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

How do you store the header names?

I would use CSV module in Python (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) but if you 
already have all header names listed then you can use "join" and
just append the row on the top of the file.

```
header_row = header_name_list.join(",")

file_to_read = open("your file path" , "r") 
old_content = file_to_read.read()
file_to_read.close()

content_to_write = "%s\n%s" % (header_row, old_content)
file_to_write = open("your file path" , "w")
file_to_write.write(content_to_write)
file_to_write.flush()
file_to_write.close()
```